# MS Outlook email templates adding extra spacing

Tags: outlook, html-table, html-email

I have made a template for an email that I have been working on for my company. The only problem is any time its forwarded from ms office it adds spacing in between the tables in the template. Is there anyway to stop this from happening? Its not there when the email arrives fresh from outlook only when its forwarded. So is there any code I can add to stop this?

[image]

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />

    <title>Email Template Version 3</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        /* Base Table Resets */
        body { margin: 0; padding: 0; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; -ms-text-size-adjust: none; }
        table { border-spacing: 0; }
        table td { border-collapse: collapse; }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Main Email Setting (Background Color) -->
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="background" style="background-color: #CCCCCC; background-repeat: repeat-x" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top">
                <!-- Super Top Header -->
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="650">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left" height="30" width="325"><span style="font-size: 12px; font-weight: normal; color: rgb(122, 122, 122); font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; text-decoration: none;">July 31st, 2013</span></td>

                        <td align="right" height="30" width="325"><span style="font-size: 12px; color: rgb(122, 122, 122); font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;">Having trouble viewing this email? <a href="#" style="color: #0075AA; text-decoration: none;">Click Here!</a></span></td>
                    </tr>
                </table><!-- /Super Top Header -->

                <!-- Header -->
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background-color: #FFFFFF" width="650">
                    <tr>
                        <!-- Left Corner -->
                        <td width="15"><img alt="Left Corner" border="0" height="110" src="http://partspro.com/email/img/corners/tlcorner.gif" width="15" /></td>

                        <td align="left" valign="middle" width="620">
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="620">
                                <tr>
                                    <!-- Parts Pro Logo -->
                                    <td width="184">
                                        <a href="http://www.partspro.com"><img alt="Parts Pro Logo" border="0" height="76" src="http://partspro.com/email/img/logos/partspro.gif" width="184" /></a>
                                    </td>

                                    <td width="3">&nbsp;</td>
                                    <!-- Newswire Logo -->
                                    <td width="345"><img alt="Parts Pro Newswire" border="0" height="76" src="http://partspro.com/email/img/logos/newswire.gif" width="345" /></td>

                                    <td width="3">&nbsp;</td>

                                    <td>
                                        <!-- Social Media Top Icons -->
                                        <table border="0" style="padding-left: 1px;" width="83">
                                            <tr>
                                                <!-- Facebook -->
                                                <td>
                                                    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/PartsProCenters" target="_blank"><img alt="Facebook" border="0" height="37" src="http://partspro.com/email/img/icons/facebook.gif" width="39" /></a>
                                                </td>

                                                <!-- Linked In -->
                                                <td>
                                                    <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/groups/Parts-Pro-Performance-Centers-4867941" target="_blank"><img alt="LinkedIn" border="0" height="37" src="http://partspro.com/email/img/icons/linkedin.gif" width="39" /></a>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>

                                            <tr>
                                                <!-- Twitter -->
                                                <td>
                                                    <a href="https://twitter.com/PartsProPerform" target="_blank"><img alt="Twitter" border="0" height="37" src="http://partspro.com/email/img/icons/twitter.gif" width="39" /></a>
                                                </td>

                                                <!-- Youtube -->
                                                <td>
                                                    <a href="http://www.youtube.com/user/PartsProCenters" target="_blank"><img alt="YouTube" border="0" height="37" src="http://partspro.com/email/img/icons/youtube.gif" width="39" /></a>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table><!-- /Social Media Top Icons -->
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>

                        <!-- Right Corner -->
                        <td width="15"><img alt="Right Corner" border="0" height="110" src="http://partspro.com/email/img/corners/trcorner.gif" width="15" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table><!-- /Header -->

                <!-- Featured Image Table -->
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background-color: #FFFFFF; padding: 0 15px;" width="620">
                    <tr>
                        <!-- Featured Image for the Email -->
                        <td align="center"><img alt="Featured Image" height="200" src="http://partspro.com/email/img/headers/header.png" width="620" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table><!-- /Featured Image Table -->

                <!-- Main Body Table -->
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;" width="650">
                    <tr>
                        <!-- Feature 1 -->
                        <td style="font-size: 12px; color: rgb(122, 122, 122); line-height: 150%; font-family: trebuchet ms; padding: 15px;" valign="top" width="420">
                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="420">
                                <tr>
                                    <!-- Feature 1 Image -->
                                    <td>
                                        <img alt="News Feature 1" border="0" height="260" src="http://partspro.com/email/img/features/feature1.png" width="420" /><br /><br />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <!-- Feature 1 Header -->
                                    <td height="25" valign="top"><span style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; color: rgb(51, 51, 60)">Celebrate 75 Years of Edelbrock!</span></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <!-- Feature 1 Text -->
                                    <td><span style="font-size: 12px; color: rgb(122, 122, 122); font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;">Commemorate Edelbrock's 75th Anniversary in style with these limited edition accessories. The unique air cleaner and valve covers are made of die-cast aluminum, which is then polished to a mirror-like finish and complimented with black anodized aluminum inserts that feature a laser etched design. Want a closer look? Click the link below!</span></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <!-- Feature 1 Button -->

                                    <td align="right">
                                        <a href="#"><img alt="Read More" border="0" height="32" src="http://partspro.com/email/img/buttons/readmore.gif" width="116" /></a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table><!-- Feature 2 -->

                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="420">
                                <tr>
                                    <!-- Feature 2 (Image) -->
                                    <td><br />
                                        <img alt="News Feature 2" border="0" height="260" src="http://partspro.com/email/img/features/feature2.png" width="420" /><br /><br />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <!-- Feature 2 Header -->
                                    <td height="25" valign="top"><span style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; color: rgb(51, 51, 60)">New Intake for 2012-13 Camaro!</span></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <!-- Feature 2 Text -->
                                    <td><span style="font-size: 12px; color: rgb(122, 122, 122); font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;">Airaid's new MXP-Series Cold Air Intake system ups the ante for the 2012-13 V6 Camaro with an additional 14 horsepower and 13 lb-ft of torque, with no aftermarket tuning required! Did we also mention the intake is made in the USA and backed by Airaid's "No Hassle" warranty? Well, it is. So what are you waiting for. Get your order in today! Want some more information? Click the link below!</span></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <!-- Feature 2 Button -->
                                    <td align="right" width=" 5px">
                                        <a href="#"><img alt="Read More" border="0" height="32" src="http://partspro.com/email/img/buttons/readmore.gif" width="116" /></a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>

                        <!-- Line Seperator Down the Right Side -->
                        <td valign="middle" width="1"><img alt="Divider" height="857" src="http://partspro.com/email/img/seperator.gif" width="1" /></td>

                        <!-- Right Side Bar -->
                        <td style="font-size: 12px; color: rgb(122, 122, 122); line-height: 150%; font-family: trebuchet ms; padding: 14px;" valign="top" width="169">
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="169">
                                <tr>
                                    <!-- Right Side Bar Text 1 -->
                                    <td width="169">
                                    <!-- Join the Team -->
                                     <span style="font-size: 12px; color: rgb(122, 122, 122); font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;"><strong>Join the Team!</strong><br />
                                    If you are a local Performance Automotive Aftermarket retailer, you should take a look at all the marketing programs that we have developed to help you sell more products.<br /><br />

                                    <!-- Visit our Site -->
                                     Visit our site at:&nbsp;<br />
                                    <a href="http://www.partspro.com" style="color: #0075AA; text-decoration:none;">www.partspro.com</a> and give us a call.<br /><br />

                                    <!-- Contact -->
                                     A professional account representative is ready to help!<br />
                                    <strong>Phone:</strong>&nbsp;(423) 282-0211<br />
                                    <strong>Email:</strong> <a href="mailto:jerrys@partspro.com?subject=About%20the%20Parts%20Pro%20NewsWire" style="color:#0075AA; text-decoration:none;">jerrys@partspro.com</a><br /><br /><br />

                                    <!-- What of the Week -->
                                     <img alt="What of the Week?!" border="0" height="92" src="http://partspro.com/email/img/whatoftheweek/whatoftheweek-logo.gif" style="padding: 0;" width="170" /> Right before this, he clothslined the guy at the drive-thru at Wendy's....<br />
                                    <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DpgrTyrBvlA"><img alt="What?! Of the Week Youtube Image" src="http://partspro.com/email/img/whatoftheweek/whatoftheweek.gif" style="padding: 10px 0 0 0;" /></a><br /><br />

                                    <!-- What of the Week (Image & Link) -->
                                     <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DpgrTyrBvlA"><img alt="Watch It!" border="0" height="32" src="http://partspro.com/email/img/buttons/watch.gif" style="padding: 0;" width="170" /></a>

                                     <!-- Ad Space (Image & Link) -->
                                     <a href="http://www.totaltruckcenters.com"><img alt="Total Truck Centers" border="0" height="170" src="http://partspro.com/email/img/banners/extraspace.gif" style="padding: 0;" width="170" /></a></span></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table><!-- /Main Body Table -->

                <!-- Gallary of 6 Table -->
                <table cellpadding="15" cellspacing="0" style="background-color: #FFFFFF" width="650">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center">
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="610"></table>

                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="610">
                                <tr>
                                    <!-- Minifeature 1 Image -->
                                    <td style="font-size: 12px; color: rgb(122, 122, 122)" width="200">
                                        <a href="#"><img alt="Mini Featured 1" border="0" height="200" src="http://partspro.com/email/img/minifeatures/minifeatures1.gif" width="200" /></a>
                                    </td>

                                    <td style="font-size: 12px; color: rgb(122, 122, 122)" width="5">&nbsp;</td>

                                    <!-- Minifeature 2 Image -->
                                    <td style="font-size: 12px; color: rgb(122, 122, 122)" width="200">
                                        <a href="#"><img alt="Mini Featured 2" border="0" height="200" src="http://partspro.com/email/img/minifeatures/minifeatures2.gif" width="200" /></a>
                                    </td>

                                    <td style="font-size: 12px; color: rgb(122, 122, 122)" width="5">&nbsp;</td>

                                    <!-- Minifeature 3 Image -->
                                    <td style="font-size: 12px; color: rgb(122, 122, 122)" width="200">
                                        <a href="#"><img alt="Mini Featured 3" border="0" height="200" src="http://partspro.com/email/img/minifeatures/minifeatures3.gif" width="200" /></a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <!-- Minifeature 1-3 Headings -->
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center" style="font-size: 14px; color: rgb(122, 122, 122); font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;"><strong>K&amp;N AirFilter</strong></td>

                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>

                                    <td align="center" style="font-size: 14px; color: rgb(122, 122, 122); font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;"><strong>K&amp;N AirFilter</strong></td>

                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>

                                    <td align="center" style="font-size: 14px; color: rgb(122, 122, 122); font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;"><strong>K&amp;N AirFilter</strong></td>
                                </tr>

                                <!-- Minifeature 1-3 Spacing -->
                                <tr>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>

                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>

                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>

                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>

                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <!-- Minifeature 4 Image -->
                                    <td style="font-size: 12px; color: rgb(122, 122, 122)" width="200">
                                        <a href="#"><img alt="Mini Featured 4" border="0" height="200" src="http://partspro.com/email/img/minifeatures/minifeatures4.gif" width="200" /></a>
                                    </td>

                                    <td style="font-size: 12px; color: rgb(122, 122, 122)" width="5">&nbsp;</td>

                                    <!-- Minifeature 5 Image -->
                                    <td style="font-size: 12px; color: rgb(122, 122, 122)" width="200">
                                        <a href="#"><img alt="Mini Featured 5" border="0" height="200" src="http://partspro.com/email/img/minifeatures/minifeatures5.gif" width="200" /></a>
                                    </td>

                                    <td style="font-size: 12px; color: rgb(122, 122, 122)" width="5">&nbsp;</td>

                                    <!-- Minifeature 6 Image -->
                                    <td style="font-size: 12px; color: rgb(122, 122, 122)" width="200">
                                        <a href="#"><img alt="Mini Featured 6" border="0" height="200" src="http://partspro.com/email/img/minifeatures/minifeatures6.gif" width="200" /></a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <!-- Minifeature 4-5 Headings -->
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center" style="font-size: 14px; color: rgb(122, 122, 122); font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;"><strong>K&amp;N AirFilter</strong></td>

                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>

                                    <td align="center" style="font-size: 14px; color: rgb(122, 122, 122); font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;"><strong>K&amp;N AirFilter</strong></td>

                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>

                                    <td align="center" style="font-size: 14px; color: rgb(122, 122, 122); font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;"><strong>K&amp;N AirFilter</strong></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table><!-- /Gallary of 6 Table -->

                <!-- Rebates Banner Table -->
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background-color: #FFFFFF" width="650">
                    <tr>
                        <!-- Rebates Banner (Image & Link) -->
                        <td align="center">
                            <a href="http://partspro.com/cms/rebates/"><img alt="Rebates Banner" height="100" src="http://partspro.com/email/img/banners/rebatesbanner.gif" width="650" /></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table><!-- /Rebates Banner Table -->

                <!-- Footer Table -->
                <table cellpadding="15" cellspacing="0" style="background-color: #FFFFFF" width="650">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="425">
                            <table border="0" width="420">
                                <tr>
                                    <!-- AAM Logo -->
                                    <td style="padding-right: 5px;"><img alt="AAM Logo" border="0" height="77" src="http://partspro.com/email/img/logos/aam.gif" width="122" /></td>

                                    <!-- Copyright -->
                                    <td><span style="font-size: 12px; color:rgb(122, 122, 122); font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;">Copyright © 2013 AAM Group. All Rights Reserved.<br />
                                    <!-- Address -->
                                     198 Industrial Park Road. Piney Flats, TN 37686</span><br /><br />

                                    <!-- Subscribe, Forward, Unsubscribe -->
                                     <span style="font-size: 12px; color: rgb(000, 000, 000); font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;"><a href="#" style="color:#0075AA; text-decoration: none;">Forward</a> l <a href="#" style="color: #0075AA; text-decoration: none;">Subscribe</a> l <a href="#" style="color: #0075AA; text-decoration: none;">Unsubscribe</a></span></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>

                        <!-- Social Media Mini Links -->
                        <td align="right" style="background-color: #FFFFFF" valign="bottom" width="125">
                            <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" width="155">
                                <tr>
                                    <!-- Facebook -->
                                    <td align="right" width="170">
                                        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/PartsProCenters" target="_blank"><img alt="Facebook" border="0" height="32" src="http://partspro.com/email/img/icons/facebook.gif" width="32" /></a>
                                    </td>

                                    <!-- LinkedIn -->
                                    <td align="right" width="170">
                                        <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/groups/Parts-Pro-Performance-Centers-4867941" target="_blank"><img alt="LinkedIn" border="0" height="32" src="http://partspro.com/email/img/icons/linkedin.gif" width="32" /></a>
                                    </td>

                                    <!-- Twitter -->
                                    <td align="right" width="170">
                                        <a href="https://twitter.com/PartsProPerform" target="_blank"><img alt="Twitter" border="0" height="32" src="http://partspro.com/email/img/icons/twitter.gif" width="32" /></a>
                                    </td>

                                    <!-- Youtube -->
                                    <td align="right" width="170">
                                        <a href="http://www.youtube.com/user/PartsProCenters" target="_blank"><img alt="YouTube" border="0" height="32" src="http://partspro.com/email/img/icons/youtube.gif" width="32" /></a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table><!-- /Footer Table -->

                <!-- Shadow at the bottm -->
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="line-height: 0;" width="650">
                    <tr height="10">
                        <td height="10"><img border="0" height="10" src="http://partspro.com/email/img/shadow.png" width="650" /></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td height="10"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table><!-- /Shadow at the bottm -->

                <!-- Who Sent This Email -->
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="650">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" width="310"><span style="font-size: 12px; color: rgb(122, 122, 122); font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;">This email was sent to you from: <a href="mailto:jonathanf@partspro.com" style="color: #3185c4; text-decoration:none;">jonathanf@partspro.com</a></span><br />
                        <br /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table><!-- /Who Sent This Email -->
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry but no can do. Email is a tough game to get right in the initial code, and outlook adds a TON of code upon initial reception, which gets passed along during forwarding. Have you tried forwarding another companies' HTML newsletter? I haven't had one go through without breaking all the tables, especially from outlook web app.

Answer (score 1):

```
<style type="text/css">tr {font-size:1px; mso-line-height-alt:0; mso-margin-top-alt:1px;}</style>
```

**Note:** Try the above it works fine but do give line-height property to every td element.
**References**

1. https://www.campaignmonitor.com/forums/topic/7376/outlook-2013-cell-height-bug-solution/
2. https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/removing_unwanted_spacing_or_gaps_between_tables_in_outlook_2007_2010

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the align attribute and use CSS text align.

Answer (score 0):

The MS Word html engine of Outlook adds tons of extra html to your emails.
Inserting the following lines to the style element did the trick for me :

```
/* Outlook, yahoo extra line problem :  */
.ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div {line-height: 100%;}
p {margin:0; padding:0; margin-bottom:0;}
```

Don't get tempted to hide Outlook html like so:

```
p.MsoNormal { display: none;}
```

because while it might work well in your Outlook version, it may screw up emails in other Outlook versions. (Speaking from my own meandering experience)

More info :  http://www.emailonacid.com/blog/details/C13/paragraphs_in_html_email

NB use the style section just for this type of corrections. Don't use 'common' CSS to style your elements because GMAIL will not understand it! Use inline CSS instead for every single html element!